# SQL server two instances in same machine

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use a licensed version of SQL Server along with the free version(Express Edition) of SQL?

How to install SQL server with two instances one of them licensed and the other free on the same machine? is it possible?

Comment: Please elaborate what have you tried. And where you are stuck. Explain your problem and ask a solution to that.

Comment: Read up on [named instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No differently to how you would normally install a (named) instance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have up to 50 different SQL Server instances on the same machine. One only will be the default one and its name will be the machine name. All other needs to have a specific name added to the machine name. You do not have to set a default instance (on my PC I have almost 8 different instance with SQL engine from 2008 to 2022).

Having multiple instances on the same machine is not recommended for production purpose but can be suitable for dev, test...

The minimal parameter to configure to avoid trouble, is to share the machine memory (physical RAM available) between all the instance, with the "max server memory (MB)" spreaded over the total RAM minus 2 to 4 Gb.